# Preg_split loses foreign letters

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I'm trying to use one script for keyword density. Everything works except for foreign letters (be it swedish, Estonian, or anything else).

$file includes the text.

Here's where the problem comes in:

```
$testsource = explode(" ", $file); // This has no problems with non-english letters
```

FIRST WORD in array: "Mängi"

```
$source = preg_split("/[(\b\W+\b)]/",  $file, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY); // This removes the non-english letter sometimes and also a letter in front of it
```

FIRST WORD in array: "ngi"

In case of this specific word the problem seems to be the "ä" character (and in case of other words other non-english characters) as my current preg_split removes the "Mä" from the beginning of the word. Words with no special characters are ok.

Question: What can I add to the preg_split not to cause issues?

Comment: `"/[(\b\W+\b)]/"` = `"/\W/"` - matches any non-word char. You probably want `"/\W+/u"`

Answer (score 0):

Ah, never mind, the answer is to change the preg_split line to the following:

```
$source = preg_split("/[(\b\+\b)\s!@#$%*]/",  $file, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```